# How to add HTTP trigger in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-triggers

I want add a functionality in my ADF pipeline which will send me email notification in case of failure. On searching the internet, I came to know that Azure Logic Apps helps with this. I am trying to follow below link to achieve this.

https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/03/add-email-notification-in-azure-data.html

I have tried searching up many tutorials, guides and the official docs as well. However, all of them have some templates already there in the Logic Apps Designer. I cannot find the templates and the 'When a HTTP request is received' trigger is also not available in the drop-down.

[image]

Please let me know how to proceed.

EDIT :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a blank Logic App, search for 'HTTP' or 'Request' and select Request.

[image: Logic App HTTP trigger]

On the next screen under triggers, select "When a HTTP request is received" and you should be good to go.

**EDIT:**
It looks like you created a Standard Logic App, which works in a slightly different way. For instance it can contain multiple workflows, which means you create workflows yourself. In the Consumption model, there's *one* workflow withing a Logic App, so you can open up the editor for that one directly. If there's no explicit reason for you to use Standard, a Consumption Logic App will be easier to work with.

If you *really* need a Standard Logic App, go to 'Workflows' and create a new workflow:

[image: Create new Workflow]

Then click the newly created workflow to edit it, go to 'Designer' and search for 'HTTP' to add an HTTP trigger:

[image: Add HTTP trigger]

Here's some information on the Consumption model for Logic Apps:

> | Resource type | Benefits | Resource sharing and usage | Limits management |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | **Logic App (Consumption)** Host environment: Multi-tenant Azure Logic Apps | - Easiest to get started - Pay-for-what-you-use - Fully managed | A single logic app can have *only one* workflow. Logic apps created by customers *across multiple tenants* share the same processing (compute), storage, network, and so on. | Azure Logic Apps manages the default values for these limits, but you can change some of these values, if that option exists for a specific limit. |

See [Resource type and host environment differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview#resource-type-and-host-environment-differences) for a comparison with the other hosting options.

Comment: After creating the logic app, I went on and created a new workflow and then the designer window came. I am sharing the ss of my logic app by editing the question. Please take a look. Where do I search for 'HTTP' ?
In the tutorial, they haven't created the workflow but I wasn't able to see the designer window otherwise so I created one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. I wasn't able to view a few functionalities because of another error : Functions runtime error Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').

AzureWebJobsStorage App Setting was missing which caused the error. I added that and now I can see the triggers and other stuff.

Thanks @rickvdbosch